# Lower semicontinuous envelope of the upper semicontinuous envelope of a function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u: R^n \rightarrow R$ be a given function. The lower semicontinuous envelope of $u$ is defined as the following $$u_{*} (x) = \sup_{r>0} \inf_{ 0<|y-x|<r} u (y)$$ and the upper semicontinuous envelope $u^{*}$ of $u$ is defined as $$ u_{*} (x) = \inf_{r>0} \sup_{ 0<|y-x|<r} u (y) .$$ My question is whether the following equality holds?
$$u_{*} (x) = (u^{*})_{*} (x)$$
How to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is $u: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ defined by $u(x) = 0$ if $x$ has only rational components, and $u(x) = 1$  otherwise.

Then $u_*(x) = 0$, $u^*(x) = 1$, and $(u^*)_*(x) = 1 \ne u_*(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice counter example.

Comment: @Weeson Dorne: FYI, the upper star and lower star and mixed 2-star (both possibilities) operations are idempotent: $(u^{*})^{*} = u^{*}$ and $(u_{*})_{*} = u_{*}$ and $(((u_{*})^{*})_{*})^{*} = (u_{*})^{*}$ and $(((u^{*})_{*})^{*})_{*} = (u^{*})_{*}$ See p. 429 of [*The normal completion of the lattice of continuous functions*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1950-068-03/S0002-9947-1950-0034822-9/) by Robert Palmer Dilworth (1950). Dilworth does not provide any references for these identities, but they can be found in several earlier papers. **(continued)**

Comment: I think they first appeared in [Denjoy's first published paper (1905)](http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1905__33__98_0/), a paper that seems essentially unknown, even to those whose work involves these notions (Anguelov, Dilworth, Horn, Levi, Rohwer, Rosinger, van der Walt, etc.).